# Search for bash command

Tags: bash, command-line, search

I want to search for bash commands in the bash itself. When I forget the name of a command I want a fast way to find it. For example "search for file" should suggest "find".

Comment: How about `elinks 'g:linux search for file'`?

Comment: CTRL+R followed by some consecutive characters will search your command history for a previously used command or string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest thing you can get is via one of these commands:

```
man -k search
apropos search
```

These will return all manpages whose description contains the word "search".

You can restrict the search to pages in section 1 (user commands) and 8 (admin commands) with the (non-standard) `-s` option:

```
man -ks1,8 search
```

That would omit pages about programming APIs or concepts, file formats...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My Problem with this is that there is no man page for "find".

Comment: Which Linux distro are you using? There should be a manpage for `find` on all modern distros.

Comment: Termux on Android which uses bash. There are man pages for other commands (e.g. "ssh"..).

Answer (score 1):

As @dr_ suggested using `man -k search` works well, but sometimes it gives a long list of results along with the description. So, if you want to display results nicely you can use `cut` and list only the name of commands as follows

Let say we want to find *mod (`usermod`, `groupmod`, `depmod`)

```
man -k mod | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | grep 'mod$'
```

Comment: `man -k mod | awk '$1 ~ /mod$/'` (or just `man -k 'mod$'`) would probably be more useful (if only because many of those will be about things other than commands). See also `type -m '*mod'` in `zsh` or `comgen -c | grep 'mod$'` in bash. Also `man -s1,6,8 -k 'mod$'` to restrict the search to sections 1, 6 and 8 (at least with the `man` from mandb)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas you are right. Your suggestions also worked well except `comgen -c | grep 'mod$'`. (comgen: command not found) Do you think it comes builtin or do we have to install it?

Comment: Sorry typo. That's `compgen`. See `info bash compgen`