# Search for command with wildcard

Tags: bash

I did some research, but unfortunately my question was never answered. The closest question to mine is this: [Search for bash command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/415772/search-for-bash-command)

What I need: A command to search for *installed* commands using wildcards. Let's say I want to unmount something but forgot the command. I know it contains "mount". So I would do something like this:

```
searchfor *mount*
```

To find that `unmount` is the command I need. I know `man -k` or `yum whatprovides`. But that's not what I'm looking for. I want to search for all *installed* commands (that can be found in the directories provided by the `$PATH` variable).

Comment: A bit more clarity is needed. Do you want to search for commands installed via .rpm packages or shell builtins? If so, `apropos` will do that and you don't need wildcards.

Comment: Commands installed by yum (CentOS) or apt-get (ubuntu). Okay, `apropos` is very close to my needs but not 100% what I asked for. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My favorite way is to use `compgen -c`.  For example, to find all
commands that contain `mount`:

```
$ compgen -c | grep mount
gvfs-mount
mmount
ideviceimagemounter
grub-mount
humount
hmount
umount
mountpoint
mount
fusermount
umount
mount.ntfs
mount.lowntfs-3g
mount.cifs
umount.udisks
mount.nfs
umount.nfs
mount
mount.ntfs-3g
mount.fuse
showmount
rpc.mountd
mountesp
umount.udisks2
mountstats
automount
```

What's good about `compgen -c` is that it also finds aliases, user functions and Bash built-in commands, for example:

```
$ alias aoeuidhtn='echo hi'
$ compgen -c | grep aoeuidhtn
aoeuidhtn
$ my-great-function() { printf "Inside great function()\n"; }
$ compgen -c | grep great
my-great-function
$ compgen -c | grep '^cd$'
cd
```

Also, `compgen` is a part of Bash, so it's always available.  As described by `help compgen`:

> Display possible completions depending on the options.
>
> Intended to be used from within a shell function generating possible
>   completions.  If the optional WORD argument is supplied, matches against
>   WORD are generated.
>
> Exit Status:
>   Returns success unless an invalid option is supplied or an error occurs.

Comment: Great, thanks! That's exactely what I was looking for. P.S. Thanks also for all the other answers. You guys are amazing! :-)

Comment: `grep` is a great tool, and it certainly can be useful in conjunction with `compgen -c` — for example, in the case of `compgen -c | grep mount` — but read the help text. If you know the *beginning* of the command name, you can say `compgen -c aoeuidhtn` or `compgen -c aoeui`.

Comment: When using the _Z shell_, you can use analogously  `hash | grep command`, where `hash` prints the command hash table, which holds all executables inside `$PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

```
#! /bin/bash
s=$1  # e.g. mount
IFS=:
for p in $PATH ; do
    ls "$p/"*"$s"* 2>/dev/null
done
```

Setting `$IFS` to `:` makes the `for` correctly iterate over the members of `$PATH`. Redirecting stderr to /dev/null hides error messages for directories that contain no matches.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in many different ways, look up in $PATH paths, use locate command etc..

```
 find $(echo $PATH|tr ':' ' ') -maxdepth 1 -name '*mount*'
```

Comment: with `-maxdepth 1`

Comment: And `-mindepth 1`

Comment: If any of the dirs in your PATH are symlinks, you need to use `find -H`

Answer (score 1):

For the record, in `zsh`:

```
type -m '*mount*'
```

Will find all matches and for each, report what (executable, function, alias...) and where they are.

```
$ type -m 'zc*'
zc is an alias for zcalc
zcalc is an autoload shell function
zcompile is a shell builtin
zcat is /bin/zcat
zcmp is /bin/zcmp
```

Answer (score 0):

This is based [choroba's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/434885/117037), but only uses Bash features (written for GNU Bash 4.3.11). It returns success if any matches are found, failure otherwise.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
s="${1:?}"  # Error if argument is missing or null.
exit=1  # Return failure unless changed.
IFS=:
for p in $PATH; do
    for f in "$p/"*"$s"*; do
        if [[ -f $f ]]; then
            echo "$f"
            exit=0  # Return success since match found.
        fi
    done
done
exit $exit
```